# How can I have a struct which is only used for its internal constant?

Tags: rust, constants

I need to encapsulate constants in the Rust type system. Ideally, [RFC2000](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44580) would be ready, but in its absence, and since I only need a restricted set of constants, I can implement something close to what I need:

```rust
trait U32Const {
    const VAL: u32;
}

struct U32Const10;
impl U32Const for U32Const10 {
    const VAL: u32 = 10;
}

struct MyType<X: U32Const> {
    val: u32,
    template: X,
}

impl<X: U32Const> MyType<X> {
    fn do_something(&self) -> u32 {
        self.val * X::VAL
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = MyType::<U32Const10> {
        val: 20,
        template: U32Const10 {},
    };
    println!("{}", a.do_something());
}
```

This prints out `200` as desired - that is, the constant value comes from the type that is passed in at instantiation inside `main`.

Now, this is a bit warty as it requires an instance of `X` to be created in the struct, which I call `template`, which is then unused so I get a compiler warning.

If one removes the `template` field, which is the ideal API, then the compiler complains about an unused parameter `X` on `struct MyType < X: U32Const >`. If I get rid of the `X` parameter on `struct MyType`, I then get an `unexpected type argument` on `MyType` in the the `impl` block.

Is there some way I can do what I'm trying to do that keeps the compiler happy? Effectively I want a struct which is *only* used for its internal `const`.

Comment: There is a crate that does exactly what you do, but I cannot find its name RN

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios were you thinking of [typenum](https://docs.rs/typenum/1.11.2/typenum/)?

Comment: Yes! Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios yeah probably, I just didn't know about it beforehand, so thanks :)

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios typenum is amazing and super powerful, once you grok types and trait bounds properly. For any future reader, I recommend reading [this](https://bluejekyll.github.io/blog/rust/2017/08/06/type-parameters.html) which helped me hugely.

Comment: Yes, that's a nice library. For any future reader, I hope that the const generics will be there, though ;)

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios I agree, though I think there are some things you can do with typenum that aren't possible with the const generics RFC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of giving a phantom variable into a struct, using associated types might do the trick,

```rust
trait U32Const {
    type U32;
    const VAL: Self::U32;
}

struct U32Const10;

impl U32Const for U32Const10 {
    type U32 = u32;
    const VAL: Self::U32 = 10;
}

struct MyType<X: U32Const> {
    val: X::U32,
}

impl<X: U32Const<U32 = u32>> MyType<X> {
    fn do_something(&self) -> X::U32 {
        self.val * X::VAL
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = MyType::<U32Const10> { val: 20 };
    println!("{}", a.do_something());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a53d3f0f9c8ee12f96618a8510ba4b4f) (with multiple const implementations)

Comment: It's not obvious to me what the difference is, beyond having a superfluous intermediate type (and the compiler accepting it quietly!).

Comment: @HenryGomersall the difference is you are using the generic type parameter without a extra template field and restricting the `val`'s type exactly same with the `U32Const`'s , from this point intermediate type may not seem superfluous, if you are willing to restrict it of course.

Comment: Yeah, I can see the type is used, I'm just not sure what extra info it provides to the compiler to keep _it_ happy.

Comment: @HenryGomersall please read [this section](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0738-variance.md#the-corner-case-unused-parameters-and-parameters-that-are-only-used-unsafely).

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the compiler warning by declaring `template` to have type [`PhantomData::<X>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html):

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait U32Const {
    const VAL: u32;
}

struct U32Const10;
impl U32Const for U32Const10 {
    const VAL: u32 = 10;
}

struct MyType<X: U32Const> {
    val: u32,
    template: PhantomData::<X>,
}

impl<X: U32Const> MyType<X> {
    fn do_something(&self) -> u32 {
        self.val * X::VAL
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = MyType::<U32Const10> {
        val: 20,
        template: PhantomData,
    };
    println!("{}", a.do_something());
}
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e6d8a717b1798accd861abbeaa223a51)

You still need to initialize it, but it doesn't use any memory and the compiler won't complain when you don't use it.